# How to insert multi lines to end of file using sed

Tags: sed

i want to inset multi lines befor last line in the file 
that using sed , used the following sed attr

```
> sed -i  '/\/web-app/r web.xml'  inputerror.txt
```

last line in the file

```
</web-app>
```

inputerror.txt  content as following

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/web/404</location>
</error-page>
```

nothing added to my   web.xml  any advise here

Comment: "last line in the file" - in what file? According to you, the last line in `inputerror.txt` is `</error-page>`.

Comment: How should the file look like after adding the lines ?

Comment: last line in web.xml ,  ill be adding  inputerror.txt   content to web.xml

Comment: Then you've got the filenames mixed up in your sed command. What you posted is trying to modify `inputerror.txt`, not `web.xml`.

Comment: oh my bad! i did fix it now , web.xml update .. but the input came after last line it should be before last line !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in GNU sed:

```
sed '$s@^@<error-page>\n    <error-code>404</error-code>\n    <location>/web/404</location>\n</error-page>\n@' web.xml
```

But I don't know how portable `\n` is or how to make it read from a file.